# Push to web without opt-in

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging to push to our web based application. We only need to push when the user is looking at the page - we don't need the service worker support.

If that is all we need, is there a way to set things up such that we do not need the user to opt-in? For our current use case, we are just looking to use FCM as a replacement for polling.

Maybe we should be looking to use a javascript client for Google Pub/Sub that will work in the browser?

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: The use-case you're describing does not require FCM. I'd recommend looking at something like Firebase Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore for this.

Comment: The real question is the push. The data side of things I already have handled. On App Engine in the past we used the Channel API. That is no longer available so I am looking for something to replace polling with a push solution.